# Getting description of a PBS job queue

Tags: hpc, pbs

Is there any command that would allow me to query the description of a running/ queued PBS job for its attributes such as RAM, number of processors, GPUs etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use qstat command:

`qstat -f job_id`

Comment: Thanks a lot  dimm :)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer posted by *dimm*.

If a job is registered in a queue, you can query it's attributes with `qstat` command. If the job has already finished, you can only grep relevant information from the log files. There is a handy `tracejob` command to do the grepping for you.

In PBS Pro and Torque each job registered with a queue has two sets of attributes:

- `Resource_List` has resources requested for a running or queued job
- `resources_used` holds actual resource usage for a running job.

For example in PBS Pro you could get the following attributes for `Resource_List`

```
 Resource_List.mem = 2000mb
 Resource_List.mpiprocs = 8
 Resource_List.ncpus = 8
 Resource_List.nodect = 1
 Resource_List.place = free
 Resource_List.qlist = queue1
 Resource_List.select = 1:ncpus=8:mpiprocs=8
 Resource_List.walltime = 02:00:00
```

And the following values for `resources_used`

```
 resources_used.cpupercent = 800
 resources_used.cput = 00:03:31
 resources_used.mem = 529992kb
 resources_used.ncpus = 8
 resources_used.vmem = 3075580kb
 resources_used.walltime = 00:00:28
```

For finished jobs `tracejob` could fetch you only some of the requested resources:

```
 ncpus=8:mem=2048000kb
```

and the final values for resources_used

```
 resources_used.cpupercent=799
 resources_used.cput=00:54:29
 resources_used.mem=725520kb 
 resources_used.ncpus=8
 resources_used.vmem=3211660kb
 resources_used.walltime=00:06:53
```